# knockout+jqm weird checkbox issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a block of code which is supposed to loop over an observable array, and generate a series of grouped checkboxes (as in [this example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/) ).

Here's what I'm getting instead.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/495070/shared/2012-03-28_09.03.33.000.png

here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianj774/vNcNC/13/) that demonstrates the issue.

And here's the (not as useful as the fiddle) code snippet that generates it.

```
            <fieldset id="myList" data-role="controlgroup"  data-bind='foreach : acRoleOps()'>
                <legend>
                </legend>
                <br><br><br><h4><span data-bind="text: $root.opNameGet(OperationID)"></span></h4>

                <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': 'checkbox-bcreate-' + ID, name: 'checkbox-bcreate-' + ID, id: 'checkbox-bcreate-' + ID }, checked: BCreate, click: $parent.opPrivsToggle" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="attr: { for: 'checkbox-bcreate-' + ID }">Create</label>

                <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': 'checkbox-bread-' + ID, name: 'checkbox-bread-' + ID, id: 'checkbox-bread-' + ID }, checked: BRead, click: $parent.opPrivsToggle" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="attr: { for: 'checkbox-bread-' + ID }">Read</label>

                <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': 'checkbox-bedit-' + ID, name: 'checkbox-bedit-' + ID, id: 'checkbox-bedit-' + ID }, checked: BEdit, click: $parent.opPrivsToggle" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="attr: { for: 'checkbox-bedit-' + ID }">Edit</label>

                <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': 'checkbox-bdelete-' + ID, name: 'checkbox-bdelete-' + ID, id: 'checkbox-bdelete-' + ID }, checked: BDelete, click: $parent.opPrivsToggle" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="attr: { for: 'checkbox-bdelete-' + ID }">Delete</label>

            </fieldset>
```

Has anyone seen this before?  If so, can you point out where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: jsFiddle link now in main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the knockout `<!-- ko foreach: myItems -->`
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

http://jsfiddle.net/vNcNC/38/

Comment: there's quite a bit of conversation and documentation on this problem already.  Did you have an example of how your little snippet would resolve the issue?  Feel free to modify one of the fiddles that I've already supplied to try to address this issue.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you've replaced the `data-bind='foreach : acRoleOps()'` on the field set with the `ko foreach` construct.  Thanks for the fiddle, it changes my vote on your post from a -1 to a +1, and the approval to boot.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

document.ready() doesn't work on jQuery mobile because pages are dynamically loaded. Instead, use the `pageInit` event. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vNcNC/17/ Now you've still got some issues with Knockout, but I'm not too familiar with it so I can't help with those.

Comment: yeah...I thought that wasn't right, but it worked on the fiddle I based my original template off of...and I didn't bother to change it.  Anyhow, it seems to work well enough for the example

Comment: new fiddle without the document.ready() concern.  same behavior, though.  
                 http://jsfiddle.net/brianj774/62DCh/

Comment: The script won't run like that, see this version: http://jsfiddle.net/62DCh/17/ still doesn't work though.

Comment: I don't follow you.  the base version *is* working, though I prefer your version, for ease of sight.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a conflict between the time KO is generating your markup and the time jquery mobile is applying its custom skinning. I found one issue with your code. I think the foreach is on the wrong element. I wrapped your fieldset in a new div and applied the foreach to that.

```
<div data-bind='foreach : acRoleOps()'>
                <fieldset id="opsList" data-role="controlgroup">
```

I'm not too familiar with jquery mobile but here's how I proved that this is the case. I removed the references and just checked that KO generated the correct markup. With the above change it appears to do so.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/THG9F/

Here is the jquery mobile only version with the generated markup pasted in.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/tuWgM/1/

As you can see KO is generating the correct markup, there is just a timing conflict.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have an example where I removed all the KO parts, and it works, even without the wrapping div (but no reason it shouldn't) pretty similar to what you have there....unfortunately, I need this to work with the KO bits.  I agree its a timing issue, but I'm so new with both jqm and ko (I have spent the last few years doing classic asp and flex work), that I just don't really 'get' it yet.  For simple things, yes, but not one we venture into deeper waters...

Comment: what strikes me as odd is the exceedingly deep nesting that happens...if you were to double the number of checkboxes in the fieldset...you will double the number of 'nestings' as well....only, I can't see anything in my code that would suggest such behavior, its GOT to come from the foreach bit....its like I'm missing an ID or something, and each item in the list matches each other one, so they all get it applied, one for each item....or something...

Comment: The difference the wrapping div made was that instead of getting one single fieldset with 2 sets of inputs/legends you get 2 fieldsets. Looking at the jquery mobile docs it appears you need the pagebeforecreate event http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html which can manipulate the markup before jqm does it's thing.

Comment: what do you think needs to be done in pagebeforecreate ?  .. I Agree with you about the div.  Its the right way to do that, for sure.  But it doesn't appear to change to actual behavior any.

Comment: I think you're saying that the 'ko.applyBindings' code should happen in the pagebeforecreate.  Am I reading you rightly?  I'll try it....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brianj774/62DCh/ ... I've put the ko.ApplyBindings in pageinit, pagebeforeshow, and pageshow.  None of the three positions seem to make any real difference

Comment: Yes your bindings need to fire before jqm does its thing so they can create the markup, then jqm won't know the difference. I tried simply alerting on the pagebeforecreate and nothing happened so something isn't working. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm getting the logs to fire off in that latest fiddle (up two from here).

Comment: @reidLinden - That fiddle has no js, did you include the correct link?